# How to implement google like search textbox in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application. In which i have a textbox according to the textbox values I want to  list search items from database to grid in view without postback. I am new to MVC if this question is wrong, kindly correct  me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your new to ASP.NET MVC i suggest these tutorials, they are free.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight

To answer your question you will need to do the following (high level)

1. write some JavaScript / JQuery that makes an Ajax request sending the textbox value, this should fire on the KeyUp event after a little delay, also after x amount characters have been entered to get some meaningful results.
2. This Ajax request will call a Controller Action where you can do the Database Lookup, this will return JSON.
3. Your Javascript should render the results so the user can select a result and this will populate the textbox, the user can then click the search button to do the search

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete is a plugin that can do most of the client side functionality that I  mentioned above.

This is a nice  ASP.NET MVC AJAX tutorial:

http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

**UPDATE**

1. Your Javascript should render the results so the user can select a result and this will populate the textbox, the user can then click the search button or this could be fired without the last click, anyhow you will have to re-bind / render your grid with the selected filter applied, this would have to be another AJAX request.

You may want to consider using one of these to help with the data binding and AJAX calls

**Flexigrid**: http://flexigrid.info/

**jQuery Grid**: http://www.trirand.com/blog/

**jqGridView**: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGridView

**Ingrid**: http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/

**SlickGrid** http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

**DataTables** http://www.datatables.net/index

Comment: you are advising me to do autocomplete in textbox and after clicking on the button it again call to action in controller then fill the grid in the view. Actually  I mean on textbox textchange it will call to action in the controller then fill back the grid in the view. Is it possible...?